Combining LuxAlgo - Nadaraya-Watson "Smoothers" and "Envelope" Indicators
I am new to trading actions. I am free user of Trading View. There is indicator limit to use for free users. So I want to try combining LuxAlgo - Nadaraya-Watson "Smoothers" and "Envelope" Indicators.
float y2s = na
float y1s = na
float y1_ds = na
line l = na
label lb = na

if barstate.islast and repaint
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2s := sum / sumw
        d = y2s - y1s
        
        //Set coordinate line
        l := array.get(ln,i)
        line.set_xy1(l,n-i+1,y1s)
        line.set_xy2(l,n-i,y2s)
        line.set_color(l,y2s > y1s ? dnCss : upCss)
        line.set_width(l,2)
        
        if d * y1_ds < 0
            label.new(n-i+1, src[i], y1_ds < 0 ? '▲' : '▼'
              , color = color(na)
              , style = y1_ds < 0 ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down
              , textcolor = y1_ds < 0 ? upCss : dnCss
              , textalign = text.align_center)

        y1s := y2s
        y1_ds := d


//
float y2 = na
float y1 = na

nwe = array.new<float>(0)
if barstate.islast and repaint
    sae = 0.
    //Compute and set NWE point 
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        sum = 0.
        sumw = 0.
        //Compute weighted mean 
        for j = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
            w = gauss(i - j, h)
            sum += src[j] * w
            sumw += w

        y2 := sum / sumw
        sae += math.abs(src[i] - y2)
        nwe.push(y2)
    
    sae := sae / math.min(499,n - 1) * mult
    for i = 0 to math.min(499,n - 1)
        if i%2
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 + sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) + sae, color = upCss)
            line.new(n-i+1, y1 - sae, n-i, nwe.get(i) - sae, color = dnCss)
        
        if src[i] > nwe.get(i) + sae and src[i+1] < nwe.get(i) + sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▼', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = dnCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        if src[i] < nwe.get(i) - sae and src[i+1] > nwe.get(i) - sae
            label.new(n-i, src[i], '▲', color = color(na), style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = upCss, textalign = text.align_center)
        
        y1 := nwe.get(i)

I tried to combine them but somehow I always missing "Smoothers" line, (I guess y1s, that added "s" to the end because y1 is "Envelope"s line probably.): The result I got
But should be like this:
The desired view
Is there anyone willing to combine them and send the code for me or maybe tell what am I missing?
